# how to pass a variable in to controller using jquery ajax from url

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I want to pass an id to a function in controller any suggestion. It shows cannot find the method in the controller

This is my view

```
function Delete1(id) {

        if (confirm("are u sure !")) {


            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: '/Register/Delete?id',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == "success") {
                        alert("Your account deleted successfully");
                        window.location.href = "/Register/Index";
                    }
                }

            });

        }

    }
```

This is  my controller

```
  public JsonResult Delete(int id) {


        userTable x = db.userTables.Where(y => y.ID == id).FirstOrDefault<userTable>();
        db.userTables.Remove(x);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: data: { id:"35" }, when i use hard coded value in to data it working as expect but its not catching my function parameter when i change it into  data: { id:id },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value using `data` property of ajax.Check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

like this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Register/Delete",
        data: { id : 1 },
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {

        }
    });
```

Comment: it showing only how to pass by ajax how can i catch my value in controller

Comment: the backend is c# or java?

Comment: im using c sharp

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the url correctly: url: @Url.Action("Delete","ControllerName")' and your code should read the value.